# Webpage elements move when I restore down the page

Tags: html, css

Every time I view my webpage when my browsers (Firefox) screen is maximized, all is good. But when I restore down( opposite of maximize) the screen, my UL list items reposition themselves from where they were once before. I searched for the solution and found what I thought to be. From what I was reading, I should use the absolute position. When I did that I had no luck. Then I tried "clear:both" but to no avail as well. Can someone shed some light on why this is happening? The below HTML is what I am using. Then the CSS you will see is the external css file you see me linking to.

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>QuipStir</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/alltrimmings.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
  <meta name="description" content="Users ">
 <style>
 </style>
 <script>
  document.createElement('header');
  document.createElement('nav');
  document.createElement('section');
  document.createElement('article');
  document.createElement('aside');
  document.createElement('footer');
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<header>
<div id="header_list">
 <ul>        
<li><a href="profile.php">MY PROFILE</a></li>
    <li><a href="profile.php">NEST UPDATES</a></li>
    <li><a href="profile.php">FEATURED UPDATE</a></li>
    <li><a href="profile.php">OCCUPATION INFORMATION</a></li>
    <li><a href="profile.php">MESSAGES</a></li>
    <li><a href="profile.php">MY PERSONALITY</a></li>
    <li><a href="profile.php">MY PET</a></li>
    <li><a href="profile.php">EDIT PROFILE</a></li>
<li><a href="account.php">ACCOUNT</a></li>        
<li><a href="help.php">HELP</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php">LOG OFF</a></li>
</ul>
  </div>
 <h4>Quip-Stir</h4> 
</header>
</div>
</body>
</html>


//Below is where my external CSS begins. Thank you all for any help you can provide.




html,
body{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 max-width:1600px;
 min-width:320px;
}

body {
background-color:#EBECE4;
} 



header{
background-color:#8b2323;
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 1px 1px 0px rgb(58,78,70);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px black;
     box-shadow:         0px 1px 1px 0px black;
     height:23px;
}

h4{
color:#FFE7BA;
margin:0px;
font-style:italic;
}


#header_list ul {
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
float:right;
} 


#header_list ul li{
display:inline;
}

   #header_list ul li a:hover{
    color: white;
    background-color:grey;
   }

   #header_list ul li a{
   Font-size:12px;  
   font-weight:bold;
   font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
   text-decoration:none;
   padding:5px 12px;
   color:#FFF8DC;
   text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px black;
   height:10px;
   }
```

Comment: By the way, when it repositions the UL list items, it forces them below the others that still fit within the provided area. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your css, change your `min-width` value:

```
body
{
    min-width: 1200px;
}
```

This should keep your elements from squeezing together, as that is how I have interpreted your problem.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that your `min-width` is too small right now.

Comment: Yes this seems to work great in Firefox! When I switched to IE8 and tried it, all went well except one thing. The "log off" list item still repositioned for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to change

```
body {
  min-width: 320px;
}
```

to

```
body {
  min-width: 1300px;
}
```

or potentially something greater than `1300px`, if you want it to be wider.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/UHIPUFux/1/